# Klockwork Error: RH.LEAK (2:Error) Analyze Resource acquired to 'socFd' at line 385 may be lost here

Tags: c++, c++11, klocwork

When we are trying to generate the Klockwork report it is showing

```
FrameTxRxMngr::sendStrmReqInfoToTarget(
    void
) {

    uint32_t           retVal    = IPNEXT_SUCCESS;
    uint32_t           timeout   = TIMEOUT_IN_MS;
    stFrameHeader      frameHdr{};
    struct sockaddr_in destAddr{};

    SOCKET socFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (socFd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("sendStrmReqInfoToTarget() Socket creation failed");
        retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_SCKT_CRT_FAIL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct sockaddr_in localAddr;

        localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        // ! Copy the IP address to localAddr.sin_addr
        memcpy(&(localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr),
                &m_pIpCfginfo->x86SrcIPAddr,
                sizeof(m_pIpCfginfo->x86SrcIPAddr));

        localAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);

        //! attempt to bind the socket to specific IP address
        int32_t bindResult = bind(socFd,
                                (SOCKADDR *)&localAddr,
                                sizeof(localAddr));

        if (bindResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("ERROR: bind failed with %d for sendStrmReqInfoToTarget\n",
                    WSAGetLastError());
            retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_UDP_BIND_FAIL;
        }
        else
        {
            //! set the address family to IPv4
            destAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

            // ! Copy the IP address to m_destAddr.sin_addr
            memcpy(&(destAddr.sin_addr.s_addr),
                    &m_pIpCfginfo->c10DestIPAddr,
                    sizeof(m_pIpCfginfo->c10DestIPAddr));

            destAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);
        }

        if (retVal == IPNEXT_SUCCESS)
        {
            //! Set the timeout value for the socket connection, if it fails
            int32_t sockoptResult = setsockopt(socFd,
                                            SOL_SOCKET,
                                            SO_RCVTIMEO,
                                            (const CHAR *)&timeout,
                                            sizeof(int32_t));

            if (sockoptResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("sendStrmReqInfoToTarget setsockopt for SO_RCVTIMEO Failed");
                retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_UDP_RECV_TIMEOUT;
            }
        }
    }

    //! Send the num of stream to process to target
    if (retVal == IPNEXT_SUCCESS)
    {
        int32_t bytesSent = sendto(socFd,
                                   (CHAR *)m_pTxRxConfig->pActStrmToProcess,
                                   sizeof(stActiveStreamFiles),
                                   0,
                                   (sockaddr*)&destAddr,
                                   sizeof(destAddr));

        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendStrmReqInfoToTarget sendto failed with ErrCode: %d\n",
                    WSAGetLastError());
            retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_UDP_SENDTO;
        }
    }

    if (retVal == IPNEXT_SUCCESS)
    {
        //! Receive data using the socket connection and store it
        int32_t bytesRecv = recvfrom(socFd,
                                    (CHAR *)&frameHdr,
                                    sizeof(stFrameHeader),
                                    0,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);

        if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            //! Check if the error is due to timeout
            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            {
                printf("sendStrmReqInfoToTarget recvfrom Timeout!! Didn't recv all the data");
                retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_UDP_RECV_TIMEOUT;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("sendStrmReqInfoToTarget recvfrom failed ErrCode: %d",
                        WSAGetLastError());
                retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_UDP_RECVFROM;
            }
        }
    }
  
    if (retVal == IPNEXT_SUCCESS)
    {
        //! Incase negative ack received
        if (!frameHdr.isFrmAckSuccess)
        {
            retVal = IPNEXT_ERR_NEG_ACK;
        }
    }
   closesocket(socFd);
    return retVal;
    
}
```

```
# Error: frametxrxmngr.cpp:500 RH.LEAK (2:Error) Analyze
Resource acquired to 'socFd' at line 385 may be lost here.
  * frametxrxmngr.cpp:385: Resource is acquired: 'socFd' in the call to 'socket'
  * frametxrxmngr.cpp:500: Resource is lost: 'socFd'
Current status 'Analyze'
```

Even after removing the `closesocket(socFd);` getting the same error.

Comment: might be complaining about calling `closesocket` on `INVALID_SOCKET`?

Comment: Side note your code has a high level of "C" style coding is that intentional? In C++ thinks like SOCKET would be an RAII object. And I would not expect calls like memcpy at all.

Comment: If you are still getting a resource leak warning from Klocwork even after removing the closesocket(socFd);, it's possible that Klocwork is detecting a different resource leak or is not able to accurately track the resource handling in your code. Check out the line number where Klocwork has shown the error before and after 'closesocket(socFd);' . do you see any change ?